# Pattern recognition problem having figures

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern

The following pattern was given to me by one of my friend:
If
[image],
[image] and
[image]
then, what is the value of
[image]
**My Thoughts:**
From the first figure we conclude each clock is represented by its equivalent hour value,
so $$9+9+3=21$$
From second figure we conclude each calculator is represented by its sum on its display,
so $$10+10+10=30$$
but third figure is little bit tricky with the consideration of fourth figure;
I think each bulb is decoded as two digit value with the following rules:
Unit's digit $\to$ number of arrows on the bulb , and
Ten's digit $\to$ number of bulbs
so, $$15+15-15=15$$
$\therefore$ answer is

> $9+9*34= \boxed{315}$

Is there any better decoding of figures exists? or my logic is the best??

Comment: Do you really need to go to such complexity with the light bulbs or can you just say each radiating line is worth 3 points, making the three 4-line bulbs together (i.e. 12 radiating lines) worth 12x3=36? That would be simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 other ways to look at the bulbs

> First the three bulbs in the last row could actually be
>
> 14+14+14=42  since each one is 10 plus the lines at the top. This
> gives 387 as the answer

Secondly

> Each bulb has 3 horizontal lines at the bottom portion. So the bulb
> could represent 5 top lines multiplied by the 3 horizontal lines
> (5*3=15)
>
> It is hard to see the horizontal lines in the last picture but if they
> are 3 also then each bulb is 12 so the three bulbs are 36 and the
> answer is 9+9*36=333